# How to filter results in access based on checkbox value

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, filter

I'm doing an access database and I want to apply a filter in order to display some records on a report. This database is for a shop. Each bill has this information (in a table): unique bill number, client name, if the bill has been payed (or not) and other information not necessary for what I want to ask. The field on the record that indicates if the bill payment has been recieved (or not) is a checkbox. I want to display in a report (or in a form) only the pending payments, showing in a list the client name and the bill number. I have this code, but it works on the contrary I want (it shows the payed bills and hides the unpayed ones):

```
Dim sFil As String
sFil = "Payment_recieved"
Me.Filter = sFil
Me.FilterOn = False
```

I know that checkboxes have 'True' or 'False'. In this case, I only want to display the records which "Payment_recieved" value is "False". Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `sFil = "Not [Payment_recieved]"` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson doesn't works...

Comment: @GordThompson Yes it works! To avoid problems I turned off the filter. How I do accept your answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this code, but it works on the contrary I want (it shows the payed bills and hides the unpayed ones)

In that case you can use the `Not` operator to simply invert the effect of the filter string:

```
sFil = "Not [Payment_recieved]"
```